# Sort lines of strings by number of occurrences

Tags: c#, string, sorting, duplicates

I'm still in the beginning stage of learning C# and I encountered a problem while sorting the strings by number of occurrences in a file.

Here is my code so far:

```
string[] listLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"F:\VS\AI.xls");

Array.Sort<string>(listLines); // sort alfabeticaly
System.Console.WriteLine("History of experienced feeds:");

/*
foreach (var line in listLines) //loop to return lines in alfabetical order
{
    Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
}
*/

// counts occurrences
var dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (var value in listLines)
{
    if (dict.ContainsKey(value))
        dict[value]++;
    else
        dict[value] = 1;
}

foreach (var pair in dict)
    Console.WriteLine("{1} times {0}", pair.Key, pair.Value);

System.Console.WriteLine("");
System.Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to see most common feeds:");

Console.ReadKey();

/* Finds duplicates and sorts them alphabetically */
System.Console.WriteLine("Most common:");
var duplicates = listLines.GroupBy(i => i) 
                          .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                          .Select(g => g.Key);

foreach (var d in duplicates)
    Console.WriteLine(d);
```

As you can see this can be divided into two parts. First, I count each string to get number of times they occur. Then, I display only those that occur more than once - in alphabetical order.

What I need is something in-between: a way to display repeating strings but in order from least occurrences to most occurrences.

Can you direct me in the correct way of achieving this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var strings = new string[] { "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c" };
var mostPopular = strings
    .GroupBy(s => s) //removed unnecessary count
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count());
mostPopular.ToList().ForEach(g => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", g.Key, g.Count()));
```

What `GroupBy` does is selects three of `IGrouping<string,string>`.

Each grouping contains a `Key` (the value we're grouping on) and a set of strings (the values matching that key.)

One key is "a", then the set of grouped elements is ["a", "a"], so the `Count` is 2.
Another key is "b", and the set of grouped elements is ["b", "b", "b"] so the `Count` is 3.

That's a literal explanation but I think it makes it sounds more complex and confusing. I prefer to think of it as similar to

```
SELECT s, count(*) from strings GROUP BY s ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

Comment: that works! Can you write in couple sentences please what actually happened here? Thank you!

Comment: I'm starting with the list of strings, then using Linq `GroupBy`. That creates a grouping, which has a key (the original string) and a collection of the items that are grouped by that key. That way we can look at the count of items matching that key. It's roughly the equivalent to `SELECT s, count(*) from strings GROUP BY s ORDER BY count(*) DESCENDING`

Comment: Thank you very much Scott. Your answer is working perfect and Your code is what I was looking for. Thank you for the explanation, I will study it to be able to recreate the solution in the future. Thanks!

Comment: I removed one detail from the `GroupBy` and marked it with a comment. It's unnecessary - you can tell that if it's removed it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 2):

Linq comes to rescue :)

```
new [] { "A", "Be", "D", "C", "Be", "C", "D", "C"}
.GroupBy(v => v)
.Select(g => new { Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
.OrderByDescending(g => g.Count)
.Select(g => g.Value)
```

gives:

```
C 
Be 
D 
A
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your code:

```
foreach(var str in dict.Where(p => p.Value > 1).OrderBy(p => p.Value).Select(p => p.Key))
  Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Comment: You need to add the line after you populate dict. Is your dict get populated?

Comment: It does I think because the second part of code works.

Comment: I added a clause to show only strings with more than 1 occurrence.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(KeyValuePair kvp in dict.Where(x => x.Value > 1) 
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)) 
      Console.WriteLine(kvp.Key);
```

Comment: I think you need to add Where clause to show lines with > 1 occurrence.